# Explanation of the invoke( ) method in compiled JAVA class for a JSP page

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tags

On exploring the compiled Java file for a JSP page, I came across the **invoke( )** method. This method simple had a switch case and based on the value of a discriminator variable, it executed either of **invoke0( )** or **invoke1( )** method. What's the intent of such a calling method that invokes methods that are only differentiated by **single-digit suffix**? Below is the compiled code of the **invoke( )** method (just for reference).

```
public void invoke( java.io.Writer writer )
  throws javax.servlet.jsp.JspException
{
  javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out = null;
  if( writer != null ) {
    out = this.jspContext.pushBody(writer);
  } else {
    out = this.jspContext.getOut();
  }
  try {
    Object _jspx_saved_JspContext = this.jspContext.getELContext().getContext(javax.servlet.jsp.JspContext.class);
    this.jspContext.getELContext().putContext(javax.servlet.jsp.JspContext.class,this.jspContext);
    switch( this.discriminator ) {
      case 0:
        invoke0( out );
        break;
      case 1:
        invoke1( out );
        break;
    }
    jspContext.getELContext().putContext(javax.servlet.jsp.JspContext.class,_jspx_saved_JspContext);
  }
  catch( java.lang.Throwable e ) {
    if (e instanceof javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException)
        throw (javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException) e;
    throw new javax.servlet.jsp.JspException( e );
  }
  finally {
    if( writer != null ) {
      this.jspContext.popBody();
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the occurrence of the **invoke( )** method was only once. Where is this method invoked in the JSP page?